# Failed to open access to network share exception ,when try to create sharefolder

Tags: c#, winforms, security, networking, wmi

I trying to create a shared-folder using Wmi , every-time i trying to do so i get this exception :

> Error from CreateSharedFolder(localPath=C:\BaseFolder). Ex=>Failed to open access to network share on xxx.xx.x.xxx.

trying to search for solution for days...

CreateSharedFolder:

```
        private bool CreateSharedFolder(string localPath)
    {
        try
        {
            string sharedName = shareName(localPath);
            Connection conn = Connection.GetConnection(this);
            if (conn == null)
            {
                SetAllProcessStatus(ProcessStates.ServerConnectionFailure, DetecorProcessStatuses.ServerDisconnected); ;
                Globals.WriteLog(LogTypes.Error, "Aborting CreateSharedFolder(machineInfo=" + this.ToString() + ", localPath=" + localPath + "). Got NO connecion!");
                throw new Exception("Create shared folder failed because get connection failed");
            }

            string cmd = string.Format(@"cmd.exe /c md ""{0}""", localPath);
            Run_Remote_Process_Using_WMI(conn, cmd, true);
            cmd = string.Format(@"net share {0}=""{1}"" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL", sharedName, localPath);
            bool success1 = Run_Remote_Process_Using_WMI(conn, cmd, true) > 0;

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);

            string cmd2 = string.Format(@"net share {0}=""{1}""", sharedName, localPath);
            bool success2 = Run_Remote_Process_Using_WMI(conn, cmd2, true) > 0;

            // Open access to network share (requires username & password)
            Process process = new Process();
            string args = string.Format("/c net use \\\\{0} {1} /USER:{2}", this.Address, this.Password, this.Username);
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", args);
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            if (!process.Start() ||
                !process.WaitForExit(5000) ||
                process.ExitCode < 0)
            {
                string error = string.Format("Failed to open access to network share on {0}", this.Address);
                throw new Exception(error);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.WriteLog(LogTypes.Error, "Error from CreateSharedFolder(localPath=" + localPath + "). Ex=>" + ex.Message, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and  Run_Remote_Process_Using_WMI function :

```
    try
        {
            ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
            ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(conn.ManagementScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

            ManagementClass startup;
            startup = new ManagementClass("WIN32_ProcessStartup");
            startup.Scope = conn.ManagementScope;
            startup["ShowWindow"] = (Int32)3;
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            inParams["CommandLine"] = cmd;
            inParams["ProcessStartupInformation"] = startup;


            ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

            bool success = Convert.ToInt32(outParams["returnValue"]) == 0;
            if (!success)
            {
                Globals.WriteLog(LogTypes.Error, "Failed to run remote process [" + cmd + "] on " + this.Address +
                                                 ". return value=" + outParams["returnValue"]);
                if (throwIfError)
                    throw new Exception("Failed to run WMI command: " + cmd);
            }
            if (success)
            {
                processID = Convert.ToInt32(outParams["processId"]);
                Globals.WriteLog(LogTypes.Info, "Process [" + cmd + "] on " + this.Address + " was started successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.WriteLog(LogTypes.Error, "Error from Run_Remote_Process_Using_WMI(). Ex=>" + ex.Message, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return processID;
    }
```

Comment: You are not checking `success1` or `success2` to see if the previous command succeeded. Are you sure that the network share was created?

Comment: @BerndLinde i already checked success1 and success2 return true .